# How to create toggle button that only toggles once

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I want to create a button that, when pressed, toggles to a different format and stays that way, not allowing the user to toggle it back. For example, I am trying to create a button that says "Special 1" then when it is clicked by the user, it toggles to say "USED". When the word "USED" pops up on the UIButton, it stays that way and the user cannot change it back. Please help me out I can't figure this out. I am also open to other ideas to execute this other then a UIButton, for example maybe a UITableView??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What you can do is create a boolean (true or false) variable in your ViewController, and whenever the button is tapped you set this variable so that the tap function associated with the button can be manipulated.**

1.) Make an action connection from your ViewController to your code this can be done by clicking the dual view button (the two circles in the top right corner) then holding control and drag your button into your code. :

For more information on connecting views to your code: https://codewithchris.com/9-hooking-it-all-up-swift-iboutlet-properties/
Skip to 6 min for the actual connection.

[image]

2.) Now we can just make our boolean variable, and make a basic if statement:

```
var didClick:Bool = false


@IBAction func touchButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if !didClick { // If didClick is false
        didClick = true // Set it to true
        sender.setTitle("USED", for: .normal)
    }

}
```

Note: The sender should be set to UIButton NOT `Any`

Should look like this:
`_ sender: UIButton`

Comment: I will try this today and let you know the results @Andre Assadi

Comment: Awesome, if this answered your question in the best manner, go ahead and press the check mark. This helps others identify the solution to the problem as well as giving credit to contributors :) @JimHalpert

Comment: one more question, is it possible to apply the date the button is used too? For example, instead of clicking the button and it saying just "USED" how would I get it to say the date that it was used. For example, the button is clicked on January 1st 2018, how would I get it to read "USED 01/01/18"? And on the contrary, if it was used the second of january it would need to read "USED 01/02/18" @Andre Assadi

Comment: @JimHalpert I really think you should look at some videos on programming in swift, or doing more research. I would try https://classictutorials.com/2015/07/how-to-get-current-day-month-and-year-in-nsdate-using-swift/ then using string concatenation, or in swifts case string interpolation, https://oleb.net/blog/2017/01/fun-with-string-interpolation/ to combine the dates into your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a storyboard you can write this inside the IBAction function:

```
@IBAction func buttonName(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    // Do whatever you need to do after...
}
```

sender's type could be UIButton or Any depending on how you made the connection from the storyboard.